# Change id width percentage with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to code a percentage goal bar. I can't seem to change the #bar width percentage in javascript. Any advice?? Sorry for the messy code. I have a reason for the -20 * -1. I just need to focus getting the id width percentage to change.

**CSS :**

```
.graph {
  width: 500px; /* width and height are arbitrary, just make sure the #bar styles are changed accordingly */
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #888; 
  background: rgb(168,168,168);
  position: relative;
}
#bar {
  height: 29px; /* Not 30px because the 1px top-border brings it up to 30px to match #graph */
  width: 34%;
  float: left;
  background: rgb(255,197,120); 
  border-top: 1px solid #fceabb;
}
```

**JS :**

```
var _first = -20 * -1;
var _second = 150;
var _third = _first / _second * 100;
document.getElementById('bar').style.width = _third + "%";
```

**HTML :**

```
<center><div id="progress" class="graph"><div id="bar"></div></div></center>
```

Comment: What does the above display?

Comment: Did you try moving the `script` code to the end of your HTML? I'm thinking that the `document.getElementById` is not finding the `#bar` element. I would recommend putting it into a load event or something, though.

Comment: You need to move your script after the html,because at the time you are trying to get the div with id *bar* it is not rendered yet.

Comment: Works if the script is exectued after the html part: https://jsfiddle.net/6cr36v0t/

Comment: Either move your `<script>` tags to the end or use jQuery and `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @JohannesJander Introducing jQuery is probably not necessary. OP could simply just call `window.onload`.

Comment: I just simply had to move my script under the html. Rookie mistake. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right. Just out of order. When your JavaScript tries to manipulate the DOM, it is not yet created by the browser. There are two ways of doing it and here is the way I do it. I like this way because there is not the need for an extra function to be called in order to wait for the DOM to be created.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .graph {
            width: 500px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid #888; 
            background: rgb(168,168,168);
            position: relative;
        }
        #bar {
            height: 29px;
            width: 34%;
            float: left;
            background: rgb(255,197,120); 
            border-top: 1px solid #fceabb;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- The HTML needs to come before the JavaScript. That way
          the DOMS are created for the JavaScript  -->
    <center>
        <div id="progress" class="graph">
            <div id="bar"></div></div>
    </center>

    <script>
        var _first = -20 * -1;
        var _second = 150;
        var _third = _first / _second * 100;
        document.getElementById('bar').style.width = _third + "%";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something like that. Rookie mistake. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, BNicholas. Please upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Because the JS is loaded before the DOM is ready it could not find the `div` withe id `bar` that is not loaded yet, you should put your code inside `onload` function :

```
window.onload=function(){
    var _first = -20 * -1;
    var _second = 150;
    var _third = _first / _second * 100;

    document.getElementById('bar').style.width = _third + "%";
}
```

Hope this helps.